# MS Powerapps: Forall in combination with Office365.SendEmail

Tags: powerapps

At some point in the powerapps application im am getting a collection like this:
`Collect(emailAdressenA,Admin1_Email.Text,Admin2_email.Text,Fiatteur1_email.Text,Fiatteur2_email.Text,Fiatteur3_email.Text)`
This way i create a collection of email adresses.

Then at another point in the application, i want to set an email to all of these adresses, so i tought of using the forAll option here:

```
Set(mailTitle, "Form ready"); 
Set (mailBody, "Remarks: " + AOpmerkingPar1);
ForAll(emailAdressenA,Office365.SendEmail(Value,mailTitle, mailBody))
```

obviously this doenst work as `Value` for `SendEmail` has no real value now.
is there any way to pass in the values from the collection as if this were an foreach statement (c#)? i noticed there is no foreach statements in powerapps though

Comment: Your expression should work - I created an app with a button with exactly that `ForAll` expression (changing `AOpmerkingPar1` for a constant), and clicking it sent the e-mail to all e-mails in the collection `emailAddressenA`. What kind of error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Set`, try `UpdateContext`. For example: 
`UpdateContext({mailTitle: "Form ready"});`